# Replacing Bitfields with Bitshifting in an Embedded Register Struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded, unions

I'm trying to get a little fancier with how I write my drivers for peripherals in embedded applications.

Naturally, reading and writing to predefined memory mapped areas is a common task, so I try to wrap as much stuff up in a struct as I can.

Sometimes, I want to write to the whole register, and sometimes I want to manipulate a subset of bits in this register.  Lately, I've read some stuff that suggests making a union that contains a single `uintX` type that's big enough to hold the whole register (usually 8 or 16 bits), as well as a struct that has a collection of bitfields in it to represent the specific bits of that register.

After reading a few comments on some of these posts that have this strategy outlined for managing multiple control/status registers for a peripheral, I concluded that most people with experience in this level of embedded development dislike bitfields largely due to lack of portability and eideness issues between different compilers...Not to mention that debugging can be confounded by bitfields as well.

The alternative that most people seem to recommend is to use bit shifting to ensure that the driver will be portable between platforms, compilers and environments, but I have had a hard time seeing this in action.

My question is:

1. How do I take something like this:

   ```
   typedef union data_port
   {
       uint16_t CCR1;
       struct
           {
               data1 : 5;
               data2 : 3;
               data3 : 4;
               data4 : 4;
           }
   }
   ```

   And get rid of the bitfields and convert to a bit-shifting scheme in a sane way?
2. Part 3 of this guys post [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/best-way-handling-memory-mapped-registers-any-c-ahmed-nasr-eldin/) describes what I'm talking about in general...Notice at the end, he puts all the registers (wrapped up as unions) in a struct and then suggests to do the following:

   > define a pointer to refer to the can base address and cast it as a pointer to the (CAN) register file like the following.
   >
   > ```
   > #define CAN0 (*(CAN_REG_FILE *)CAN_BASE_ADDRESS)
   > ```

   What the hell is this cute little move all about?  CAN0 is a pointer to a pointer to a function of a...number that's #defined as CAN_BASE_ADDRESS?  I don't know...He lost me on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard does not specify how much memory a sequence of bit-fields occupies or what order the bit-fields are in. In your example, some compilers might decide to use 32 bits for the bit-fields, even though you clearly expect it to cover 16 bits. So using bit-fields locks you down to a specific compiler and specific compilation flags.

Using types larger than `unsigned char` also has implementation-defined effects, but in practice it is a lot more portable. In the real world, there are just two choices for an `uintNN_t`: big-endian or little-endian, and usually for a given CPU everybody uses the same order because that's the order that the CPU uses natively. (Some architectures such as mips and arm support both endiannesses, but usually people stick to one endianness across a large range of CPU models.) If you're accessing a CPU's own registers, its endianness may be part of the CPU anyway. On the other hand, if you're accessing a peripheral, you need to take care.

The documentation of the device that you're accessing will tell you how big a memory unit to address at once (apparently 2 bytes in your example) and how the bits are arranged. For example, it might state that the register is a 16-bit register accessed with a 16-bit load/store instructions whatever the CPU's endianness is, that `data1` encompasses the 5 low-order bits, `data2` encompasses the next 3, `data3` the next 4 and `data4` the next 4. In this case, you would declare the register as a `uint16_t`.

```
typedef volatile uint16_t data_port_t;
data_port_t *port = GET_DATA_PORT_ADDRESS();
```

Memory addresses in devices almost always need to be declared `volatile`, because it matters that the compiler reads and writes to them at the right time.

To access the parts of the register, use bit-shift and bit-mask operators. For example:

```
#define DATA2_WIDTH 3
#define DATA2_OFFSET 5
#define DATA2_MAX (((uint16_t)1 << DATA2_WIDTH) - 1) // in binary: 0000000000000111
#define DATA2_MASK (DATA2_MAX << DATA2_OFFSET) // in binary: 0000000011100000
void set_data2(data_port_t *port, unsigned new_field_value)
{
    assert(new_field_value <= DATA2_MAX);
    uint16_t old_register_value = *port;
    // First, mask out the data2 bits from the current register value.
    uint16_t new_register_value = (old_register_value & ~DATA2_MASK);
    // Then mask in the new value for data2.
    new_register_value |= (new_field_value << DATA2_OFFSET);
    *port = new_register_value; 
}
```

Obviously you can make the code a lot shorter. I separated it out into individual tiny steps so that the logic should be easy to follow. I include a shorter version below. Any compiler worth its salt should compile to the same code except in non-optimizing mode. Note that above, I used an intermediate variable instead of doing two assignments to `*port` because doing two assignments to `*port` would change the behavior: it would cause the device to see the intermediate value (and another read, since `|=` is both a read and a write). Here's the shorter version, and a read function:

```
void set_data2(data_port_t *port, unsigned new_field_value)
{
    assert(new_field_value <= DATA2_MAX);
    *port = (*port & ~(((uint16_t)1 << DATA2_WIDTH) - 1) << DATA2_OFFSET))
                   | (new_field_value << DATA2_OFFSET);
}
unsigned get_data2(data_port *port)
{
     return (*port >> DATA2_OFFSET) & DATA2_MASK;
}
```

---

> ```
> #define CAN0 (*(CAN_REG_FILE *)CAN_BASE_ADDRESS)
> ```

There is no function here. A function declaration would have a return type followed by an argument list in parentheses. This takes the value `CAN_BASE_ADDRESS`, which is presumably a pointer of some type, then casts the pointer to a pointer to `CAN_REG_FILE`, and finally dereferences the pointer. In other words, it accesses the CAN register file at the address given by `CAN_BASE_ADDRESS`. For example, there may be declarations like

```
void *CAN_BASE_ADDRESS = (void*)0x12345678;
typedef struct {
    const volatile uint32_t status;
    volatile uint16_t foo;
    volatile uint16_t bar;
} CAN_REG_FILE;
#define CAN0 (*(CAN_REG_FILE *)CAN_BASE_ADDRESS)
```

and then you can do things like

```
CAN0.foo = 42;
printf("CAN0 status: %d\n", (int)CAN0.status);
```

Comment: I think you should review the "new_field_value |= (new_field_value << DATA2_OFFSET);". Bitfields are easier... :-)

Comment: @linuxfan Thanks, fixed. Bitfields are easier to get right the first time, but that's what unit tests are for. Bitwise operations are easier to use in real-world projects.

Comment: I really disagree on your last thought. I understand the problems about portability, endianness and so on. But I prefer better and (hopely) uniform C compilers than the messy shifting and masking I made for 30 years now. Things are getting better, let them get better.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that each register subset (data2, in your answer) needs it's own pair of read and write functions?

Comment: @testname123 Not necessarily: you could make a single function that takes the offset and size as parameters. It's a compromise between convenience, code size and performance.

Answer (score 2):

1.
The problem when getting rid of bitfields is that you can no more use simple assignment statements, but you must shift the value to write, create a mask, make an AND to wipe out the previous bits, and use an OR to write the new bits. Reading is similar reversed. For example, let's take an 8-bit register defined like this:

```
val2.val1
0000.0000
```

val1 is the lower 4 bits, and val2 is the upper 4. The whole register is named REG.
To read val1 into tmp, one should issue:

```
tmp = REG & 0x0F;
```

and to read val2:

```
tmp = (REG >> 4) & 0xF;   // AND redundant in this particular case
```

or

```
tmp = (REG & 0xF0) >> 4;
```

But to write tmp to val2, for example, you need to do:

```
REG = (REG & 0x0F) | (tmp << 4);
```

Of course some macro can be used to facilitate this, but the problem, for me, is that reading and writing require two different macros.

I think that bitfield is the best way, and a serious compiler should have options to define endiannes and bit ordering of such bitfields. Anyway, this is the future, even if, for now, maybe not every compiler has full support.

2.

```
#define CAN0 (*(CAN_REG_FILE *)CAN_BASE_ADDRESS)
```

This macro defines CAN0 as a dereferenced pointer to the base address of the CAN register(s), no function declaration is involved. Suppose you have an 8-bit register at address 0x800. You could do:

```
#define REG_BASE 0x800     // address of the register
#define REG (*(uint8_t *) REG_BASE)

REG = 0;    // becomes *REG_BASE = 0
tmp = REG;  // tmp=*REG_BASE
```

Instead of `uint_t` you can use a struct type, and all the bits, and probably all the bytes or words, go magically to their correct place, with the right semantics. Using a good compiler of course - but who doesn't want to deploy a good compiler?

Some compilers have/had extensions to assign a given address to a variable; for example old turbo pascal had the ABSOLUTE keyword:

```
var CAN: byte absolute 0x800:0000;  // seg:ofs...!
```

The semantic is the same as before, only more straightforward because no pointer is involved, but this is managed by the macro and the compiler automatically.

Comment: “I think that bitfield is the best way, and a serious compiler should have options to define endiannes and bit ordering of such bitfields” This is not how it usually works. Most compilers don't have options to define the ordering of bit-fields, and even for those that do, it can be a pain to use the right options when different parts of a source tree need different settings (because not every project accesses only a single piece of hardware, e.g. an OS often compiles all of its drivers with the same options). And relying on such optoins locks you down to a specific compiler.

Comment: @Gilles things are not easy, but the tag `embedded` implies a subset of what you describe. Moreover, "options" of the compiler should be written with #pragmas near the relevant piece of code, otherwise is a non-sense.

Comment: @linuxfan gcc manual: *Note that in general we do not recommend the use of pragmas;*

Comment: Compilers won't get any closer towards a standardized size, order, and endianess before the standard is going to define them. And the standard will most probably not agree with you that bitfields need to be more standardized than they already are. Most experienced programmers I know stay well away from bitfields if possible.

Comment: @tofro Compilers don't have to standardize bitfields. They have to give the programmer the power to define endianness and similar. Using pragmas or attributes or whatever. Otherwise, I don't see the point to use bitfields. C has made made many many improvements, let us continue this way, let us urge standards to improve, instead of using standards to stop the good development.

Comment: @linuxfan You can use bitfields to store bits. That's about it. And you need to live with the place, order and packing the compiler chose for you.

Comment: @tofro it seems that bitfields are little understood. They are useful to lay out hardware registers and protocols (UDP, ethernet and so on). I never used them for stupid flags. Take a look at the hardware registers of a Renesas RX processor, for example, then tell me if you still want to use bitmasks and shifts. And I DONT have to take what layout the compiler choose for me - I tell the compiler how to arrange those fields, even GCC can do it and the linux kernel does use bitfields where appropriate.